# Why am I seeing this unexpected behavior from .NET's StartsWith?

Tags: c#, .net

This must be a .NET bug, right?

`"KonNy".StartsWith("Kon")` returns false, while `"KonNy".StartsWith("Ko")` and `"KonN".StartsWith("Kon")` return true.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you by any chance a Hungarian? Hungarian collation would explain the phenomenon (although I don't know if .NET's `StartsWith` implements collation details), given that `nny` is a single letter.

Comment: Most likely you have some non-standard characters in your string

Comment: Amadan, great observation. Mind answering so I can accept it?

Comment: Either a *really* weird culture, or some unusual characters in there. Can you print the codepoints for all characters? something like `foreach(char c in "KonNy"){Console.WriteLine((int)c);}`

Comment: No unusual characters, I'm using Hungarian culture and indeed nny is a letter in Hungarian.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Repeated from comments:

I don't know .NET specifically, but I suspected you might observe this phenomenon if `StartsWith` followed a collation where `nny` was a single letter, such as Hungarian. If I'm right and if you change your collation to a neutral one, your "bug" would disappear. :)

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: This is a culture sensitivity issue, which only shows in Hungarian cultures. Repro:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        foreach (var culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
        {
            if (!"KonNy".StartsWith("Kon", false, culture))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(culture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hu
hu-HU
```

If you want a culture-insensitive comparison, specify `StringComparison.Ordinal` as per usr's answer.

Comment: This is exactly how I reproduced it outside the environment where I encountered it. Returned false. Funny thing is, in PowerShell it returned True.

Comment: That only disproves his claim for your culture, and as you know cultures can be weird. You should iterate over all cultures in a loop to check.

Comment: @ggPeti: Well the program I've written prints True. Does it *really* print `False` for you?

Comment: It really really REALLY does. I hand-typed it so as to avoid similar looking characters.

Comment: @ggPeti: Edited - what's your current culture?

Comment: Hungarian. Amadan made a good point in the question comments: in Hungarian, nny is a letter.

Comment: @ggPeti: Edited - that's the problem. See my edit for a program to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your string has some zero-width or non-printable characters in it. The Unicode character space contains some nasty, unintuitive surprises. Try calling ToCharArray on your string literals and inspect the resulting char codes.

And try calling StartWith with StringComparison.Ordinal to ensure that your culture doesn't interfere.