# Does the culture of the StringComparison type of String.Equals matter?

Tags: c#

In C#, you can compare two strings with `String.Equals` and supply a `StringComparison`.

I've recently been looking to update my archaic method of comparing `ToLower()` because I read that it doesn't work on all languages/cultures.

From what I can tell, the comparison types are used to determine order when confronted with a list containing `aé` and `ae` as to which should appear first (some cultures order things differently).

With `string.Equals`, ordering is not important. Therefore is it safe to assume that many of the options are irrelevent, and only [Ordinal] and [Ordinal]IgnoreCase are important?

The [MSDN article for String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) says

> The comparisonType parameter indicates whether the comparison should
>   use the current or invariant culture, honor or ignore the case of the
>   two strings being compared, or use word or ordinal sort rules.

`string.Equals(myString, theirString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

I'd also be interested to know how the sort method works internally, does it use `String.Compare` to work out the relative positioning of two strings?

Comment: "With `String.Equals`, ordering is not important" --can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: It returns a bool, rather than any sorting information, so it doesn't matter if the strings would be placed before or afterwards in a list, it only matters if they are equal

Comment: Oh ok, right. I was confused thinking you were trying to do ordering with equals or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Case insensitive comparisons are culture dependent. For example using Turkish culture, `i` is not lowercase for `I`. With that culture `I` is paired with `ı`, and `İ` is paired with `i`. See [Dotted and dotless I on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I).

There are a number of weird effects related to culture sensitive string operations. For example [`"KonNy".StartsWith("Kon")` can return `false`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063084/why-am-i-seeing-this-unexpected-behavior-from-nets-startswith).

So I recommend switching to culture insensitive operations even for seemingly harmless operations.

---

And even with culture insensitive operations there is plenty of unintuitive behavior in unicode, such as multiple representations of the same glyph, different codepoints that look identical, zero-width characters that are ignored by some operations, but observed by others,...

Comment: I see, interesting. Which StringComparison method would you recommend?

Comment: `Ordinal*` for internal data, and current culture for user data, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919

Comment: Does CurrentCulture mean the culture of the string, or the culture of the environment? I guess on a webserver you might have trouble if it runs in the UK but serves people in Turkey

Comment: A string has no culture, it's just a sequence of characters. It uses the culture of the current thread. Depending on the configuration of your webserver, that may well be the clients culture.