# Why str.swapcase().swapcase() != str in Python

Tags: python, string, methods

I read [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=swapcase#str.swapcase) that `s.swapcase().swapcase() == s` is not always true. Why not? When I read this, I thought this might have something to do with the `.casefold` method; but I couldn't figure that out and couldn't find anything with an Internet search.

Comment: To provide some clarity to your question, you could at least specify what language you're talking about (by adding the necessary tag), and link to the documentation you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

This is because lowercase-to-uppercase (and vice-versa) is not always a 1:1 mapping. Here's an example:

```
s = "ı"
s.swapcase().swapcase() == s
# => False
```

This is 'LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I' (U+0131) used in Turkish. Capitalised version of it is just "I", just like the capitalised version of "i" outside Turkey. (Capitalised version of "i" in Turkey is "İ".) So there are two ways to lowercase "I": the one used in Turkey, and the one used everywhere else. `swapcase` does not know which one you need.

You would get a similar result for `s = "İ"`: `"İ".swapcase()` is `i`, but `"i".swapcase()` is `"I"`.

Here is another example: `s = "ς"`. That one is 'GREEK SMALL LETTER FINAL SIGMA' (U+03C2), which differs from `"σ"`, 'GREEK SMALL LETTER SIGMA' (U+03C3), in that it is the variant letter only used at the end of the word. But in uppercase, there is no difference, it is always `"Σ"` — 'GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA' (U+03A3). `swapcase` does not check whether the character would be at the end of the word, so `"ς".swapcase()` becomes `"Σ"`, but `"Σ".swapcase()` yields the normal sigma, `"σ"`.

Comment: Oh okay i see thanks for the explanation

Comment: I would have think each language has it’s own reference to a similar letter, but it is pretty much logical in fact lol

Comment: The result isn't necessarily even the same *length*. From German: `'ß'.swapcase().swapcase()` becomes `'ss'`.

Comment: In some languages such string manipulation functions are locale-sensitive — [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063084/why-am-i-seeing-this-unexpected-behavior-from-nets-startswith) gave me a laugh — but Python's `swapcase` is not aware of which language and which country you are trying to conform to, and just picks the most common answer if multiple possibilities exist. Python's built-in locale sensitivity only goes as far as providing locale-sensitive comparison in `locale` module; for anything more, there is PyICU library.

Comment: Ah yep Karl i seen it in the doc also i was wondering if there was any analogy with the casefold exemple as i said in my question indeed it is obvious now that i think to it, i guess i was too tired to think correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Amadam, ill check out for this module! also yeah the link you gave me is very funny ahah i laughed too, this is an astonishing behavior, even more because it is an auto detection which you didn’t ask for Oo

Comment: Thanks for the exemple update also im just seeing it is a good one, can i ask you if there is any solved badge to check now ?

Comment: Yep — the green checkmark to the left of an answer.